# DbSets in DbContext are null .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am trying to access tables in a database, but the DbSets are null.

Here is the first half of my model (it matches the view in my SQL Server Database):

```
[Table("vwAccounts")]
public class Account
{
    [Column("AccountId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("AccountUserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    
    [Column("AccountPassword")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column("AccountActive")]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [Column("CompanyId")]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Column("DriverId")]
    public int DriverId { get; set; }

    [Column("AccountTypeName")]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

[image: table column definition]

Here is my DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
       
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }

}
```

Here is my program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:myConString"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

...
app.Run();
```

And here is where I'm trying to access the DbSets, but they are null:

```
 public IEnumerable<Account> GetAccounts()
 {
      try
      {
           // HERE is the error.
           // db.context.Accounts is null, so it doesn't matter what method I call from it, it throws the error
            Account results = dbContext.Accounts.First();
            Console.WriteLine(results);
                           
            return results;
       } catch (Exception ex)
       {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
       }
}
```

This is the actual error message:
[image]

Using the debugger, dbContext.Accounts is not null, it is {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1[MySite.Models.Entities.Account]}.
When I try to access anything in dbSte is where the issue occurs.

After digging into the debugger stack trace, I beleive the issue might have to do with incorrect variable typing.

```
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
   at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`1.get_Items()
```

Comment: Are you sure `dbContext.Accounts` is null and not `dbContext` itself? Can you please share the whole class?

Comment: None of the stuff I’m missing should pertain to the issue. The accounts class is just more fields, and program.cs just has more setup stuff. I can try to update it, but I got a warning about having too much code

Comment: From your code, There is nothing unusual, Can your provide the error message? bwt, Are you using code first or db first in ef core?

Comment: @XinranShen What do you mean code first vs database first? Nothing is auto genereated, but the tables were designed first. If that's what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
After commenting out properties until I narrowed down the issue to these properties, I realized the data in the database has null values. So I fixed this by making my integers nullable:

```
 [Column("CompanyId")]
 public Int32? CompanyId { get; set; }
        
 [Column("DriverId")]
 public Int32? DriverId { get; set; }
```